# Find number of customers visiting two brands

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE customer_brand_table 
(
    customer_id Text Not NULL,
    brand_id Text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO customer_brand_table VALUES ("A", 123);
INSERT INTO customer_brand_table VALUES ("A", 234);
INSERT INTO customer_brand_table VALUES ("B", 345);
INSERT INTO customer_brand_table VALUES ("C", 234);
INSERT INTO customer_brand_table VALUES ("C", 567);
```

This is the table containing customer id and brand id. I want to count the number of customers visiting all possible **Pair** of brands. So the output would be

| brand1 | brand2 | # customers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 234 | 1 |
| 123 | 345 | 0 |
| 123 | 567 | 0 |
| 234 | 345 | 0 |
| 234 | 567 | 1 |
| 345 | 567 | 0 |

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried solving this with SQL, but you stuck somewhere? If so, please show us your query and tell us about the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

We can self join the table using `<` to create the list of combinations and then left join and use `count(distinct)` to get the number customers buying both brands.

```
select
  count(distinct c.customer_id) num,
  a.brand_id,
  b.brand_id
from customer_brand_table a
join customer_brand_table b
on a.brand_id < b.brand_id
left join customer_brand_table c
on a.customer_id = c.customer_id
and b.brand_id = c.brand_id
group by
  a.brand_id,
  b.brand_id;
```

> ```
> num | brand_id | brand_id
> --: | :------- | :-------
>   1 | 123      | 234     
>   0 | 123      | 345     
>   0 | 123      | 567     
>   0 | 234      | 345     
>   1 | 234      | 567     
>   0 | 345      | 567
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fbc435e88f7c61ec41b3abb633d23b42)*